# Foreign key constraint is not created in one-to-one relationship in jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have one-to-one relationship with the following configuration:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "org")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "default_gen", sequenceName = "haj_rasoul", allocationSize = 1)
public class Organization extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@GenericGenerator(name = "default_gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "reza"))
public class Product extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "DD")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "PP")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "MM")
    private String imageUrl;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Organization reza;

    public Organization getReza() {
        return reza;
    }

    public void setReza(Organization reza) {
        this.reza = reza;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

and the BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4295229462159851306L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "default_gen")
    private T id;

    @Column(name = "updatedby")
    private Date updatedDate;

    public Date getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

When the application is started with the update mode for creation the models,
they are created successfully but foreign key `Organization` does not exist in the `Product`, another hand the record of Organization can be deleted in the event that it is in the Product as foreign key.
Where is wrong?
How do i fix this problem?

Comment: where is the `@Id` of each class?

Comment: show the code for @Id too.

Comment: I have put the BaseEntity for @Id. please come back to the post